# the following classes could not be found :-android.support.design.widget.NavigationView"

Tags: android

When I use the `<NavigationView />` tag of `<Navigation Drawer />`, the right corner of the screen shows the line:

> "the following classes could not be found :-android.support.design.widget.NavigationView"

So how can i fix this solution?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure you have added below line in your app level build.gradle.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```

Change '26.+' according to your tarketSdkVersion.

Comment: see the image he compiling with 25

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs : In the preview section it is showing API version of the editor , not the compile version

Comment: I know that, If he has SDK 26 he will use 26 in the API version 26 only.

Answer (score 1):

You should have design library in your Gradle.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

If you have then clean and rebuild your project.

You should place your NavigationView inside DrawerLayout. Don't place inside Framelayout.

your code should like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Still no effect? Restart your studio.

Comment: Thanks , i did it :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to Sync your Gradle files

Go to
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

I had the same error , and with this i fixed it